# Magento call extra fields products in cart

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I have a problem, I need show in my store cart, same extra field values, but when I use this code:

```
$productId = $_item->getId();
$productInfo = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($productId); 
echo $productInfo->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($productInfo);
```

he returns me a error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getFrontend() on a non-object in /home/vhosts/algarve-pass.com/algarve-pass-v3/magento/app/design/frontend/default/unyktheme/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml on line 23
```

I dont know how I can solve this.

My magento version is 1.7, thanks.

Comment: what are these extra fields, i mean product attribute or anything else ?

Comment: yes, its attributes sorry

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I found the problem. I'm using the getId, and I need used the getProductId, something like that:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
echo $_product->attribute_label;
```

Done!

Answer (score 0):

if nothing is working you can try following.

```
$productId = $_item->getId();
$productInfo = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($productId);
```

then for a dropdown use

```
$attributeId = $this->htmlEscape($_product->getData('select_measurement'));
$attr = $productInfo->getResource()->getAttribute("attribute_code");
$attr->getSource()->getOptionText($attributeId);
```

and for textbox attribute use

```
$_product->getData('label_for_thickness')
```

will do the needfull.

Please check and reply fo further asistance